# C# does not accept c1, c2, c3 as defined vars

Tags: c#, scope

```
if(API>30)
{
   double c1 = 0.0178; 
   double c2 = 1.187; 
   double c3 = 23.931;
}
else
{
   double c1 = 0.0362; 
   double c2 = 1.0937;
   double c3 = 25.7240;
}

double Rs2 = (c1 * sg * Math.Pow(p, c2)) * Math.Exp(c3 * (API / T));
```

C# does not accept `c1`, `c2`, `c3` in my code as defined vars, how can I solve this ?

Comment: Would renaming them help?

Comment: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every variable has it's [definition scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). When a variable in c defined in a block (meaning between a `{` and a `}`) it is limited to that scope, meaning it can be referenced only in that scope. Therefore, in the last line you are out of the definition scope of `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and cannot refer to them.

You need to define them outside the block:

```
double c1, c2, c3;
if(API>30)
{
   c1 = 0.0178; c2 = 1.187; c3 = 23.931;
}
else
{
   c1 = 0.0362; c2 = 1.0937; c3 = 25.7240;
}

double Rs2 = (c1 * sg * Math.Pow(p, c2)) * Math.Exp(c3 * (API / T));
```

Comment: To clarify your answer: the scope of an entity determines where it can be referred to *by its unqualified name*. Local variables do not have a qualified name, so they can *only* be referred to within their scope. Compare that with `class C { public static int x; static int M() { return x; } }` -- here `x` is in scope throughout `C` and so can be referred to as `x` inside `M`. But outside of `C` (and any derived classes of `C`) you must say `C.x`. You can still refer to the variable, just not as `x`.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare them *out* of the `if/else` scope.

```
double c1, c2, c3; 

if(API>30)
{
   c1 = 0.0178; 
   c2 = 1.187; 
   c3 = 23.931;
}
else
{
  c1 = 0.0362; 
  c2 = 1.0937; 
  c3 = 25.7240;
}
double Rs2 = (c1 * sg * Math.Pow(p, c2)) * Math.Exp(c3 * (API / T));
```

Comment: I can smell the reason...but I cant find any problem declaring them within blocks in my machine. Why?

Comment: You find a problem in the moment you want to access them. Out fo the scope where they declared you can nnot access them.

Comment: Ahaan...I failed to see that. I thought OP is facing trouble in declaration itself. He is missing basic rules of programming....:)